# Angular cache interceptor problem at first requests

Tags: angular

Angular6 cache interceptor works fine, but I have a problem with first requests on the page (for example when I send request for vocabulary from few pipes/components on same page/view).

I tried something like below in my code:

```
    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
            const cachedResponse = this.cache.get(req.url);
            return cachedResponse ? of(cachedResponse) : this.sendRequest(req, next);
    }

    sendRequest(
        req: HttpRequest<any>,
        next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        return next.handle(req).pipe(
            tap(event => {
                if (event instanceof HttpResponse && this.isCachable(req.url)) {
                    this.cache.put(req.url, event);
                }
            })
        );
    }
```

Now, when I have for example six requests to one URL (for example in network i've got six time /getUsers url). I thought that interceptor firstly save my data and then use that - but this happens only after first view load.

It is problem with async? Cache just can't be on time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reasons, is that you cache the request once they are completed. So as long as the request hasn't returned, you generate a new request and don't use the cache. You have to cache the promises, not the results to prevent this.

To prevent the request from be called each time you subscribe to it you can take a look at this Article: Caching With RxJs Observables In Angular 
http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/caching-with-rxjs-observables-in-angular-2.0